# Uploading image with react and multer not working. Image not being uploaded to folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend, multer

I am trying to upload an image to a node server with multer.
I have called the API from the front end, also done the multer config at the server side, but some how, the code is not working. The image which is supposed to be uploaded in the the images folder is not being uploaded. Can someone help here?

Here is my React code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import { Router, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";

const Dashboard = ()=>{

const [userName, userNameSetter] = useState("");
const [userEmail, userEmailSetter] = useState("");

const [artTitle, setArtTitle] = useState("");
const [artContent, setArtContent] = useState("");

const [imagePreview, setPreview] = useState(undefined);
const [imageToSend, setImageToSend] = useState(undefined);



const fileUploadRef = useRef(null);

async function makePost(e){
//This function calls the api at that address.
    e.preventdefault();
    console.log("You have called the upload function");
    const fd = new FormData();

    fd.append("form-image", imageToSend);
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:1337/api/multer-photo-upload", {fd});
    console.log(response);
}





const addPostImage =()=>{
    fileUploadRef.current.click();
}




async function uploadPostImage(e){
//This function simply tests to see if the user has clicked on an image and to upload set it on the state variable. For it to be displayed
    if(e.target.files.length === 0){
        console.log("Please choose an image");
    }else{
        const imageMain = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        setPreview(imageMain);

        setImageToSend(imageMain);
    }

   
}


async function performUpload(fd){

    
}
useEffect(()=>{
    let emailAdd = localStorage.getItem("email");
    let uName = localStorage.getItem("name");

    userNameSetter(uName);
    userEmailSetter(emailAdd);
});

return (
<> 
<Header />
<section className = 'dashboard-wrapper'>
<section className = 'dashboard-left'>
    <center><h1>CW ADMIN DASHBOARD</h1></center>
    <center>   
    <span className = 'u-av'>
        <i class="ri-user-fill"></i>
        </span>
        <h3>
        Welcome {userName}. <br />Your Email is {userEmail}
        </h3>
        
    </center>

</section>

<section className= 'dashboard-right'>
    <h3>UPLOAD AN ARTICLE</h3>
    <form action = '' enctype = 'multipart/form-data' name = 'upload-article-form'>
    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Article Title' className = 'art-title' onChange = {(e)=>{
        setArtTitle(e.target.value);
    }}/><br />
    <textarea placeholder = 'Article Content' className = 'art-content' onChange = {(e)=>{
        setArtContent(e.target.value);
    }}></textarea><br />

    <div className='image-preview'>
        {
            imagePreview && <img src = {imagePreview} style = {{maxWidth: "200px"}}/>
        }
        
    </div>

    <input type = 'button' value = 'Add Image' onClick = {addPostImage}/>
    <input type = 'file'  name = 'image' id = "img-upload" className = 'img-upload' ref = {fileUploadRef}
    onChange = {uploadPostImage} />
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Upload' onClick = {makePost}/>
    </form>
</section>
</section>
<WhiteFooter />
</>
);

}
export default Dashboard;
```

Here is my Node code

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const User = require('./models/user.model.js');
const fs = require("fs");
// const formidable = require("formidable");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

const uploadPath = "../carefu_watchers/src/uploads/";
const serverUploadLocation = "images/";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, uploadPath)
    }, 
    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});




const uploadImage = multer({storage : storage});
app.use(express.json());



//This is the api being called by react
app.post("/api/multer-photo-upload", uploadImage.single("form-image"), (req, res)=>{
   res.send("You have hit the api");
});

// APP LISTINING AT THIS PORT
app.listen(1337, ()=>{
    console.log("App started on port 1337");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using the object property shorthand `{fd}`, it's not getting parsed, so instead use just `fd`.

Try this:

```
const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:1337/api/multer-photo-upload", fd);
```

**edit**

Also, change file variable to this:

```
const imageMain = e.target.files[0];
```

Comment: Still doesnt work @Traynor

Comment: try changing file like this: `const imageMain = e.target.files[0];`